# Can I ask for proof of the allegations made by moderators when banning?

Tags: support, moderation, moderators, ban

I would like to make this question very generic instead of very specific.

Take a situation here. Suppose if any user gets banned from the site so and so allegations, and if that user doesn't feel those allegations are not true. Now

Can the user ask the moderators to prove those allegations? 
Can that user go above the moderators and appeal?
If the user can appeal for the moderators decision, up to what extent of hierarchy he can appeal?

**Research that I have done:**
Since this is very specific question to SE, I have tried to search for similar questions in meta. How ever I didn't get any posts which covers my question.

Comment: Where have you been banned? I see no temporary suspension on any of your accounts. If you have been post (question / answer) banned, that is *entirely* automatic.

Comment: What were those allegations?

Comment: I suspect the downvotes are due to the vagueness of the question and the lack of any detail.

Comment: @Martijn he's banned on the [English site](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/30645/babu) it's last in the list due to the 1 rep it cause. Ramesh - it says you are suspended "for voting irregularities" which is pretty plain.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: I didn't down vote any body in the recent past. Can I ask the moderators to prove and seek for information that supports their allegations?

Comment: @Ramesh it's nothing like this. One possible reason is that you created sockpuppet accounts and used them to upvote yourself. If you are using a computer that is shared with your friends, one of them might have used it to create his own account and upvote you, and having same IP makes it look like it's the same person. The answer by Chris is the most you can do.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Not necessarily, you can reply to a mod message (which is always sent with a suspension) as well.

Comment: I'll bet two beers the allegations turn out to be true.

Comment: @Pekka Early Christmas spirit(s)?

Comment: @Pekka: having seen the allegations in question, I bet two Karlsberg Ur-Pils that he (probably rightfully) objects to exactly one word in the (boilerplate) message, while conveniently leaving out that the rest of it is spot on. (The message was not mine, I'm not biased.)

Comment: @ЯegDwight heh! I had a feeling like that (something like "but I didn't have 15 sockpuppets, but only 12! This is an outrage!"). Looks like we're both going to get drunk this Christmas!

Comment: I kept reading _alligators_ instead of _allegations_. I was wondering if the OP was referring to an Italian song: "There are two alligators, an orangutan, two little snakes, and a royal eagle..." `;)`

Comment: I see this account has also been suspended on Stack Overflow, for the same reason.

Comment: You can always talk to the team, but you barely gave the ELU mod team time to respond to your reply before posting this. We do sleep, you know.

Comment: @Oded: Now I have modified my question, can the down-votes be revoked? Where can I request to revoke the down votes?

Comment: It doesn't work that way. People _may_ review the question and decide to remove their downvotes, but there is no process for it. Consider that a downvote costs -2 and an upvote +5 and you will see that if the question is improved enough to get upvotes you will be better off.

Comment: Additionally, [downvotes on meta mean](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) disagreement.

Answer (score 17):

In the first instance reply to the moderator message explaining why you think the suspension is unjust. However, be nice. Don't rant or accuse the moderators of malice.

If you want to take the issue further then you can contact the Stack Exchange team using the [contact us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help) (meta link) at the foot of every page. Click the link on the site where you have been banned.

It lists various common actions and, if none of these apply, allows you to e-mail the team.

Answer (score 12):

Generally, "voting irregularities" means that you have used [sockpuppets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockpuppet_%28Internet%29) to inflate your reputation/revenge downvote someone else. It can also be for too much serial voting (i.e., if you give a particular user too many upvotes/downvotes). You may want to see [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/) as well.

Unfortunately, moderators cannot give the reason behind a suspension in public, so this is a bad place to ask for it. Instead, reply to the suspension message. If you feel the ban was unjust, use the [contact us form](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help)